# How can i get rid of warning messages

Tags: warnings, errors

URL:http://www.gazettevandetroit.com/

Error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/gazettev/public_html/wp-content/themes/exquisite-wp/template-home.php on line 118

Code File: http://ideone.com/VNLGKq

Note: Im not a Programmer. Please Change the code. Wordpress version 4.0.1

Comment: Please add your code directly to your question

Comment: code is too long

Comment: You should only post relevant code. Remove all irrelevant firts

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `$categories` is an empty array. To solve this always check if the array is empty or not.

In line 117 add code to check if array is empty

```
<?php if( !empty( $categories ) ){ ?>
```

and in line number 167 replace

```
<?php } ?>
```

with

```
<?php } } ?>
```

If you want to permanently remove any error or warning message you can use the php code `error_reporting(0);`. Pase this in top of your `functions.php` file.

Additionally open `wp-config.php` file and check for `WP_DEBUG`. It must be false;

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

Comment: Don't replace curlies with `:` and `endif`. It makes code hard to read and to debug. Most code editors don't support this syntax, but all support curlies

Comment: I think it's better now. I edited the answer.

Comment: Much better. Look, your original syntax is 100% valid, nothing wrong with it, it is just a pain when it comes to debugging code and reading it. It still is personal preference, but always good to know alternatives to what you are doing :-)